# Is there a set list of citizens?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

While inviting a lot of people to my kingdom, certain ones are more helpful than others. I'm wondering if the list of citizens are static, or if they are random? Will I get the same exact citizens as anyone else?

This will be very beneficial if I'm missing a certain citizen and I know that they can be found in the exact same spot as another person found them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are fixed.

Every citizen will be the same. They will always have the same requirements, and always have the same skills.

You can confirm this by comparing your list with [this one](http://www.powerpyx.com/ni-no-kuni-2-all-citizens-skills-list/), which matches with my current in-game list.